# jquery flowplayer not playing mp3

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, flowplayer

In the following code i use a flow player that is used to play a song.Muy question is that insted of http://release........ why cant i use the downloaed one which resied in my site directory
i.e, instead of this
`f("audio", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf",`
 i want to use this
`f("audio", "/var/site/media/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf",`

When i include `/var/site/media/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf` i get an error saying mp3 file not found.What am i doing wrong

```
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
     $f("audio", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf", {

        // fullscreen button not needed here
        plugins: {
           controls: {
              fullscreen: false,
              height: 30,
              autoHide: false
           }
        },

        clip: {
           autoPlay: false,

           // optional: when playback starts close the first audio playback
           onBeforeBegin: function() {
              $f("player").close();
           }
        }

     });
     });
   </script>
   <div id="audio" style="display:block;width:350px;height:30px;" href="/var/site/media/a.mp3"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MP3 player runs in your browser. The browser does not have access to your server's local file system.

You will always need to specify a URL pointing to the MP3 file like you do in your first example.

Comment: @Pekka:so u mean to say that i shold specify mysite.net/var/site/media/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf??

Comment: @Rajeev probably not: If `/var/site` is your web root, it would have to be `http://mysite.net/media.....` etc.

Comment: @Pekka:When i pointed my site to player as u described above,player loaded but the mp3 clip didnt

Comment: The exact message was, 202, The provider specified in this clip is not loaded, Provider 'audio' , clip: '[Clip] 'http://mysite/media/a.mp3''

Comment: @Rajeev that sounds like the path to the MP3 file is incorrect?

Comment: @Pekka:I give the exact path ie,http://mysite.net/media/a.mp3 also tried with /media/a.mp3.Please let me know if u need any inputs from me.

Comment: @Rajeev Sorry, I don't know what this could be. Strange.

Comment: @Pekka:Just for your info ,basurl needs to be added in clip:{}